# Как заменить значения в SQLlite таблице?

Tags: sql, sqlite

В Как правильно запрос сделать чтобы во всей таблице tab1 заменить значения NULL на 1 допустим.

Перечитал, не могу понять полностью эти запросы.

Comment: Для всех полей? Или для одного конкретного поля?

Comment: Думаю, примерно: `UPDATE tab1 SET <название столбца> = 1 WHERE <название столбца> IS NULL`

Comment: для всех полей на всей таблице

Comment: Все спасибо сработало понял теперь

Comment: Если мой ответ решил вашу задачу, то отметьте его как верный

Answer (score 2):

Ну для всех полей автоматически вы одним запросом не обновите. А вот если перечислить все поля, то тогда это делается таким запросом

```sql
UPDATE tab SET
  f1 = COALESCE(f1, 1),
  f2 = COALESCE(f2, 1),
  ..........
  fn = COALESCE(fn, 1);
```

Здесь `f1`...`fn` имена полей в таблице, а `COALESCE` [встроенная](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-functions/sqlite-coalesce/) функция, которая возвращает первый NOT NULL аргумент.

Т.е. для каждой записи поле будет обновлено своим же значением, если оно не равно NULL или 1 в противном случае

Comment: по вашему не понял первый ответил я сделал UPDATE tab1 SET PRICE = ""   WHERE PRICE IS NULL;
UPDATE tab1 SET NAME = ""   WHERE NAME IS NULL;
UPDATE tab1 SET DESCRIPTION = ""   WHERE DESCRIPTION IS NULL;